# Converting Java code to JRuby

Tags: java, jruby

I'm using some Java code in a JRuby project for connecting to MQ. I'm new in Java and don't know how the following statements of Java can be used in JRuby.

```
QueueConnection con = factory.createQueueConnection();
QueueSession session = con.createQueueSession(false, session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
session.start();
```

Where QueueConnection and QueueSession are Java classes that are imported on top

```
java_import javax.jms.QueueConnection
java_import javax.jms.QueueSession
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java:

- Variable must declare their type. `QueueConnection con = ...` means the variable `con` is of type `QueueConnection`. Types exists in Ruby too but they are not explicit, so you would simply say `con = ...`.
- Statements must be ended by semi-colons. They are not required in Ruby.

Additionally, the code you show is not quite correct, as the `session` variable is used in `session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` before it is declared. `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is a static field of the `QueueSession` class, so the code should read `QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`. In JRuby, static fields can be accessed using the `::` syntax instead of `.`.

I would therefore guess that the equivalent JRuby code of your snippet is something like this:

```
con = factory.createQueueConnection()
session = con.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession::AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
session.start()
```